# Why maple computes $\prod_{k=3}^{\infty} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)$ as $0$?

Tags: maple

I have computed the infinite multiplication using Maple, $\Pi_{k=3}^{\infty} ( \cos (\frac{\pi}{k} ))$, as follows, but it resulted in **0**! I wonder why this happened, although maple was using exact arithmetic.

```
P := Product(cos(Pi/k), k = 3 .. infinity)
value(P)
```

Note that if I use floating-point instead, it gives me the right answer, **0.1149420449**.

```
evalf(P)
```

By the way, I did not expect such a situation! Exact arithmetic should be exact! I am multiplying non-zero numbers to each other, starting from $1/2$ to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So it should not be zero! *Why such a thing happened?*

Note: Maple is a proprietary Computer Algebraic System that I have access to through my university's lab.

Comment: Have you cross-checked with other CAS?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, I just have checked it against Maple. I just wonder why such a thing happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! I have asked this question on several other forums and the following is the summary of the responses and shall be assumed as **answer**.

The reason that this happens in Maple is a solving the equation $\cos(\Pi/k)=0$ and finding all of its integer roots in $\left[ 3 , \infty \right)$ to see if it is zero or not ($product$ is some sort of a smart function in maple, rather than trying to multiply the numbers in order, it first checks for short circuits). The solution to this equation would be of the general form $k=\frac{2}{1+2*i}$ for integer $i$. But, Maple has a $3$-valued logic, so the value of a logical expression could be either *true*, *false*, and *Undefined*! The developer of $Product$ unfortunately seems to forget this, Maple is closed-source and no access to the source code, and ruined everything!

P.S.: This answer is a summary of [the same question asked in www.mapleprimes.com](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/201006-Why-Does-Maple-Compute-prodk3infty-cos-left?sort=odate) by me.

Answer (score 6):

Convergence issues are quite commonly bad handled by CASs.

I remember older versions of Mathematica giving
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cos(n\pi) = \frac{1}{2},$$
for istance. Anyway, from the Weierstrass product for the cosine function, namely:
$$\cos(z) = \prod_{m=0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2(2m+1)^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$\log\cos\frac{\pi}{k}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{4}{k^2(2m+1)^2}\right)=-\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{4^n}{k^{2n}(2m+1)^{2n}},\tag{2}$$
and summing over $m$ we get:
$$\log\cos\frac{\pi}{k}=-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(4^n-1)\cdot\zeta(2n)}{n\cdot k^{2n}}\tag{3}.$$
Now summing both sides of $(3)$ with $k$ that goes from $3$ to $+\infty$ gives:
$$\prod_{k=3}^{+\infty}\cos\frac{\pi}{k}=\exp\left(-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}(4^n-1)\cdot\zeta(2n)\cdot\left(\zeta(2n)-1-4^{-n}\right)\right)\tag{4}$$
where the terms of the sum in the RHS behaves like $(4/9)^n$ ensuring pretty fast convergence. Is is also quite interesting to notice that, by the Euler reflection formula for the Gamma function,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{4^n}{d^{2n}}\cdot\frac{\zeta(2n)}{n}=-\log\left(\frac{d}{2\pi}\sin\frac{2\pi}{d}\right).\tag{5}$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice proof of convergence. But I am curious to know why Maple does so!